# Different numbers in math-mode and regular text

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, fontspec, math-fonts

I am using `libertine` package with `newtxmath`. For text the math font suffices, but when it comes to numbers the two don't gel well. For example, in the MWE appended below, the numbers in the equations and equation labels are different.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way this can be avoided. For example, using the regular text font for numbers in the math mode?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

The area ($A$) was related to the sides ($x$) by the following relation
\begin{equation}%
A = 10 \times x
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
The area $A$ of a square with side $x$ given by
\begin{equation}%
A = x^{2}
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}
We consider the equation for volume of a cube
\begin{equation}%
v = x^{3}
\label{eq3}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried using the solution given by Ulrike Fischer on linked duplicate question, but it is not working for Linux Libertine. The fonts are still coming different.